# Starting a Service from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

The parts of this application in question are an `IntentService` (`DatabaseService`) and an `AppWidgetProvider` (`LotWidget`). In `LotWidget`, when a button is pressed, a `PendingIntent` is fired which sends a broadcast to itself, and is received in `onReceive()`. All of this works fine so far. In `onReceive`, I read the action from the `Intent` as well as the various extras, and either start this `IntentService`, or start the main `Activity`. Starting the activity works fine, but for some reason I can't understand, the `DatabaseService` isn't being started. I know code leading up to the `DatabaseService` intent is being sent by testing with `Log`.

Here is the `onReceive` code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if(intent.getAction().equals(RETURN_DATA_WIDGET) && initialize(context)){
        updateWidget(context);
    }
    else if(intent.getAction().equals(INTERNAL_INC)){
        Log.d("WIDG", "Incrememnt");
        Intent incr = new Intent(context, DatabaseService.class);
        incr.setAction(INCREMENT);
        incr.putExtra("incval", intent.getIntExtra("incval", 999));
        context.startService(intent);
    }
    else if(intent.getAction().equals(INTERNAL_UP)){
        Log.d("WIDG", "UPDATE");
        Intent upd = new Intent(context, DatabaseService.class);
        upd.setAction(UPDATE_COUNT);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
    else if(intent.getAction().equals(OPEN_APP)){
        Intent open = new Intent(context, TheLotActivity.class);
        open.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(open);
    }
}
```

Using the same intents to start the `DatabaseService` from the main `Activity` works fine. My manifest defines the `DatabaseService` as a `Service` like so:

```
<service android:name="com.bsprague.thelot.DatabaseService" >
    </service>
```

I know the `Service` isn't being started because a `Log` at the very beginning of `onHandleIntent` isn't being displayed, though it displays fine when this `Intent` is sent from the main `Activity`. Is there something in Android that I'm missing that makes it so you can't start a `Service` from a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You are setting an action on the `Intent`, and your `<intent-filter>` does not have that action. You might consider replacing the `setAction()` calls with `putExtra()` calls instead.</strike>

Never mind -- as you pointed out in a comment, since you are specifying the component, all other routing elements (e.g., action) are ignored. Your error from your updated comment suggests that your `Intent` is picking up the wrong component, `LotWidget` instead of `DatabaseService`.

Comment: I just tried replacing the setAction() with an putExtra(), the DatabaseService is still never being called to read for the extra.

Comment: @user1500074: Check LogCat for warnings.

Comment: I'm getting this error:
'07-03 18:43:56.546: W/ActivityManager(1629): Unable to start service Intent { act=up flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.bsprague.thelot/.LotWidget bnds=[266,767][398,839] }: not found'

I was getting this earlier, then I switched from a Service to an IntentService and the error disappeared entirely. Does the issue have to do with the random slash?

Comment: @user1500074: "If I'm calling the service by name in the intent (new Intent(context, DatabaseService.class)), shouldn't it not matter?" -- actually, that's a good point.

Comment: @user1500074: I am not sure what "random slash" you are referring to. That error would be if you called `startService()` on an `Intent` whose component is `LotWidget` instead of `DatabaseService` (e.g., `new Intent(this, LotWidget.class)`).

Comment: I was referring to the seemingly stray slash in com.bsprague.thelot/.LotWidget. And the error is perplexing to me as well, because the PendingIntent broadcasts from the LotWidget to itself are firing fine.

Here's an example of that code:
`Intent incr = new Intent(context, getClass());
  incr.setAction(INTERNAL_INC);
  incr.putExtra("incval", 1);
  
PendingIntent incrbtn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, incr, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, incrbtn);`

Comment: @user1500074: That is standard `ComponentName` syntax, so that's not a problem.

Comment: I found my issue, it was an incredibly simple mistake on my part. I use startService(intent) instead of the actual intent I just created. Silly, simple stuff. Thank you for your help.